# Any disadvantages of "SQL_BUFFER_RESULT" for MySQL SELECT?

Tags: mysql, select

I've been researching the usage of SQL_BUFFER_RESULT. Mostly it is referred to as an aid to reduce table lock issues.

It seems to be a good option to use.

However I cannot seem to find any disadvantages about it. Is it an option which should be used most of the time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SQL_BUFFER_RESULT` creates a temporary table on the server for every result set.  This is not a temporary table like `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` - it is an implicit temporary table as would be created when using a GROUP BY clause or with a subquery.  As such, [all the same rules apply](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html).

First, let's talk the problem that `SQL_BUFFER_RESULT` is designed to solve:

When the client requests data from the server, until the entire result set has been transmitted to the client the query is still "running" and some locks may still be held.  While the data is being transmitted, it will appear in the `Sending data` state.  It is library dependent on whether the client just gets all the data at once when the query is executed, or if it trickles in as you select rows, but an example of a problem is as follows:

```
resultset = conn["SELECT * FROM bigtable"]
resultset.each do |row|
  data[:value] = row[:value]
  sleep 10 # do something expensive here
end
```

Obviously contrived, but in the case above if there are 1000 rows, the query will still be actively running for 10,000 seconds.  That may seem far fetched, but a lot of applications have "think time" in-between fetching each row because they do some processing.  This is "a very bad thing to do."  Another case where this type of trickle effect could occur is with a large result set over a slow connection.  Ultimately, the problem is the trickling of data to the client causing the query to remain in an active state.  `SQL_BUFFER_RESULT` resolves this problem by buffering the result into a temporary table first, which makes the query end faster, thus releasing all of its locks (what locks?).  The result set is then fed to the client from the temporary table rather than the query itself.

That sounds great!

But...

- Temporary tables take up memory and other resources on the server.  Lots of temporary tables == lots of resources.
- Tables that exceed the minimum of [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) or max_heap_table_size will end up being converted to on-disk temporary tables, which means additional I/O.  It also means that your queries take longer, as once the size of the MEMORY table reaches tmp_table_size, it is then converted to an on-disk MyISAM table.
- BLOB/TEXT fields cannot be stored as in-memory temporary tables (the MEMORY storage engine does not support them), thus will always be created on disk.
- creating temporary tables is expensive, especially when they are on-disk.
- Consider that one of the first things we try to optimize away when looking at an explain plan is "Using temporary."  `SQL_BUFFER_RESULT` literally makes every query include "Using temporary", (nearly) all the time.  My little bit of testing showed that there were cases where MySQL did not use a temporary table even with this hint, but they were limited (single row lookups on primary key seemed to be the only case).

Here are a few examples to show the effect:

```
-- unindexed lookup w/out SQL_BUFFER_RESULT
mysql> explain select  * from actor where first_name = 'THORA'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: actor
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 203
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- unindexed lookup w/SQL_BUFFER_RESULT
mysql> explain select sql_buffer_result * from actor where first_name = 'THORA'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: actor
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 203
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- indexed lookup w/out SQL_BUFFER_RESULT
mysql> explain select * from actor where last_name = 'TEMPLE'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: actor
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_actor_last_name
          key: idx_actor_last_name
      key_len: 137
          ref: const
         rows: 4
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


-- indexed lookup w/SQL_BUFFER_RESULT
mysql> explain select sql_buffer_result * from actor where last_name = 'TEMPLE'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: actor
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_actor_last_name
          key: idx_actor_last_name
      key_len: 137
          ref: const
         rows: 4
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


-- primary key lookup w/SQL_BUFFER_RESULT
mysql> explain select sql_buffer_result * from actor where actor_id = 200\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: actor
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 2
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is the problem being solved for?  "locks."  Since this is a hint for SELECT queries, unless you are using FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARED MODE, there are very few locks taken on reads anyhow and they are very fast, so you are mostly solving for a problem that doesn't exist.  Exceptions always exist, but the overhead of creating a temporary table for nearly every query will far outweigh any benefit gained from making locks go away faster.

MySQL's recommendation is to use the `SQL_BUFFERED_RESULT` hint when retrieving a very large result set over a network connection to the client.  I cannot see any value in using it in another context.

All that being said, you can test and set this "globally" by setting [sql_buffer_result](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_buffer_result)=1 at the beginning of every session.  In an environment with any concurrency, I would predict poor results.

Comment: Surely though, if the result set is very large, it'll be in a temp table anyway? This is the bit I don't understand.

Comment: No, a large result set does not necessarily mean a temporary table gets created.

Comment: @AlecTeal - For example, `SELECT * FROM huge_table` "streams" all the data directly to the client.  The client, in turn, may collect it all before handing any to the app code _or_ it may promptly hand rows off to the application code.

Comment: @AlecTeal - In contrast, `SELECT * FROM tbl GROUP BY x ORDER BY y` will need 1, probably 2, temporary tables because of the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.  All that work must be done before _any_ rows are sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing migrations like ALTER TABLE during a server upgrade which requires a table lock, non-buffered selects will block the migration and further ordinary selects will be blocked behind the ALTER TABLE. Everybody, including your production upgrade, is choked because of 1 slow client.

This hint is said to free the table lock too, so that is pretty much the only solution, regardless of the disadvantages. I would not put it on all statements, just the "exposed" statement vulnerable to slow clients.

Another solution would be to make a dedicated table and using SELECT INTO tablexyz or INSERT INTO tablexyz SELECT... The difficulty is not to drop that disposable table, but to create it with the proper columns for the resultset. There is no automatic DDL. In the end, you have the worst disadvantage (uses physical space). The only advantages of that disposable table is that you can reuse it (paging, sharing results, caching, post analysis & summaries) which the mere buffered result cannot do.